# Problem with analog passive lowpass filter

Tags: analog, low-pass, passive-filter, frequency-response, analog-filter

I designed a lC low pass filter and instead of getting a frequency response of lowpass, I got a strange frequency response as mentioned in the figure below.

Does anyone have an idea ?

The circuit:

[image]

simulated frequency response:

[image]

Measured frequency response:

[image]

Comment: The value of the inductors seems too "low". What is the "frequency" needed ... NB: it is really a "low" pass filter.

Comment: The analyzer has an input impedance of 50 ohm. Did you use that in your simulation? The 5 ohm resistors across the inductors seem incredibly low for a practical filter.

Comment: If the strange frequency response you said is the amplitude peak, that's caused by resonance.

Comment: And I don't think a 2uF capacitor is possible in IC.

Comment: The simulation looks similar with 50 ohm output resistor.
I want to pass the frequencies band 0-65 kHz and reach about -100 dB/Decade after 70kHz

Comment: Well, the passive elements used in your practical experiment are all affected by parasitics like equivalent series resistance (ESR) for the capacitors and the inductors, inter-turns capacitance for the inductors etc. All of these contributors introduce additional poles and zeroes which affect the frequency response. I would recommend you individually characterize the components you have used and reflect the parasitics back in simulation.